# web3js 1.0 fromWei throwing although passing correct type

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

I have encountered a problem with the web3js 1.0 library.

I have a simple function that is getting a balance from a smart contract:

```
async balance() {
  return await this.Marketplace.balances(this.storeOwner);
}
```

I have another function inside my angular component where I display the balance to the user:

```
async getBalance() {
  const balance = await this.smartContract.balance();
  console.log(balance);
  this.balance = this.smartContract.web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
}
```

When calling the `web3.utils.fromWei()` function I get this error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors.`

but the console log shows me, that the balance is a BigNumber object:

`BigNumber {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(1)}`

I am using version 1.0.0-beta.36. Why do I get the error?

Comment: did you try to convert `balance` to string? 
Like this: `web3.utils.fromWei(''+balance, 'ether')`

Comment: Check if you have a dependency on a different version of web3 like v0.20.

Comment: web3.js v0.x relies on `BigNumber`. web3.js v1.x relies on `BN`. To be on the safe side, use `balance.toFixed()`, which will guarantee a correct type (string) and a correct format (explicit decimal).

Comment: `balance.toString()` works.

Comment: @goodvibration you're right. I use truffle to create the smart contract instance, which uses 0.x and pass the result to my web3 1.0 method. that's why it doesn't work